# Brakes very rusty after recent replacement

Tags: brakes, rust, abs, cruze, holden

Holden Cruze 2002

[image]

front tyre

All drive or rotors are rusty now why only had them replaced spent 800. Plus other things all up spent 1580 there also abs light keep coming on

**EDIT:**

[image]

Does this picture look right to you only have just got brand new brakes drums rotors the lot it’s been nearly 2 months. I don’t drive very far in my car either.

Answer (score 1):

These don't look like drum brakes at all so your tagging is incorrect.

The rust looks like something that happens if your car is in wet weather and you don't drive a lot. Go for a long drive and brake hard often during that trip. My hybrid car has had far more severe rust on the brake rotors after I have driven in situations where I only used regenerative braking in wet weather periods, not the mechanical brakes at all. Few drives with braking hard often rescued the discs.

Your discs aren't damaged. That's only light surface rust. Go use the brakes and those will be rescued!

The ABS light is probably not related to the light surface rust on brake rotors. Reading the codes will tell what's the issue.

Comment: The brand new only just replaced

Comment: You mentioned that "Few drives with braking hard often rescued the discs".  What happened the other times?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate You parsed the sentence in a different way. "braking hard often" is meant as opposite to "braking hard rarely". "often" is part of "braking hard", it's not part of "rescued" as in "often rescued".

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, you could just clean the entire brake rotor and caliper with some brake clean, and this might be easier to do if you take off the wheels and clean it and wipe the dirt away(if you haven't used the brake cleaner before, they evaporate like alcohol so don't worry about drying the applied surface). But you don't have to do this, as you drive more the grinding action of the brake pads and rotor is going to clean itself. If I were you, I would be more worried about the metal contaminates embedded in the car's paint. But I understand not everyone really cares about that anyway.